# Is there a way to create a table using python for mysql (mysqlconnector) where the table name is user input?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Suppose I need to create a table using mysql.connector in python where the inputs will be passed using a variable, now I know that I can do that by using %s but how do I get to create a table where the name of the table itself will be a user input or a variable ?

```
askQues=str(input("Enter the name of the Table: "))
sql1="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))"
a.execute(sql1,askQues)
```

You can get an idea of what I am trying to say from the above snippet.

More detailed: Suppose I wanna create a table for each student that gets admitted to my school. Now for each of those students, the name of their tables will be named according to their serialID. Lets say a boy named John gets admitted whose serialID is ABCEXGG, Now I want to create a table named ABCEXGG which will have the fields History, Geography, Sciences and the values will be his marks for the next 10 years he will be in my school, something like this

> ABCEXGG

| History | Geography | Sciences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 98 | 97 | 95 |
| 100 | 100 | 100 |
| 92 | 100 | 99 |

Comment: Object name (table name in your case) cannot be a parameter. You must substitute it into the query text. But check it for illegal symbols absence previously for to avoid an injection.

Comment: *I wanna create a table for each student that gets admitted to my school.* Create such table automatically during new student registration. Use some name pattern like `student_table_NNNNN` where `NNNNN` is unique (primary key) value for a student taken from students table.

Comment: But primary keys can be used only as a field in some other table to relate right? (like foreign key?) How do I fetch that primary key value and create a table with it?

Comment: o_O Primary key is static table component which is used for unique row identifying (and also as an index for queries improvement). Foreign key is a rule which sets the reference to some index (most often case - primary key) in another table.